# Form validation not working with form GET method

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, getmethod

I'm trying to post my form by `method="GET"` instead of `POST`.

Codeigniter's `form_validation->run()` doesn't work.

It's not returning any `form_error` in view page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use `$_GET`, you could set the validation data before the validation rules :

```php
$this->form_validation->set_data($_GET);
```

See : [Validating an Array (other than $_POST)](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html?#validating-an-array-other-than-post)

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The concept of form_validation is based on the use POST, as the form validation function  `form_validation->run()`  builds its validation array with POST.

see Codeigniter `public function run()` at around line 417 of `system/libraries/Form_validation.php`:

> ```
> $validation_array = empty($this->validation_data)
>           ? $_POST
>           : $this->validation_data;
> ```

but as pointed out in the answer of @Hasta Dhana, you can use $_GET or any other array like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_data($_GET);
```

if you want to [validate an array that does not originate from $_POST data](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html?#validating-an-array-other-than-post). This array takes then the place of `$this->validation_data` in the if clause

Comment: But how can i validate my inputs?

Comment: please follow [Form Validation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form%20validation)

Comment: Thanks for your help